# Emacs copy region/line and comment at the same time

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I am trying to implement the following: duplicate the currently selected region or a line (if there is no selection) and comment out the original region with the help of `comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line`.

I figured I could use `kill-region` followed by `yank` but then my original selection is lost, so I can't comment. If on the other hand I comment first I will get both copies of my region commented out.

The other idea I have (which I think is better because I use evil-mode) is to use `evil-yank` and then `evil-visual-restore` to restore the selection so that I can comment it out. But I can't figure what arguments to pass to `evil-yank` to specify the selected region.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main thing you are missing is function `copy-region-as-kill`.

```
(defun copy-and-comment-region (beg end &optional arg)
  "Duplicate the region and comment-out the copied text.
See `comment-region' for behavior of a prefix arg."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (copy-region-as-kill beg end)
  (goto-char end)
  (yank)
  (comment-region beg end arg))
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I move one line down after this? I tried (next-line 1), but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: See function `forward-line`.

Comment: It doesn't work as well. I suspect it's related to evil mode, if I select the region with `V`, `forward-line` doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe post another question that is specific to whatever problem you have now.  It might be more Evil-specific, as you suspect.  (I assume you tried it without Evil mode, at least, for comparison.)

Comment: almost correct!

Comment: This is an extremely handy function for refactoring/research, along with its shorter brother `duplicate-region`. I should have searched for it a million keystrokes earlier.